# Why wont the value change in the array?

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

why is it console.logging the array with all zeroes??

im clearly changing value but its still console.logging with just zeroes

```
let a = 0,
    b = 0,
    c = 0,
    d = 0,
    e = 0
    f = 0,
    g = 0,
    h = 0,
    i = 0;

const test = document.querySelector(".test");
test.addEventListener("click", () => {
    a = 1;
    b = 1;
    c = 1;
    gameBoard.winConditions;
    console.log(gameBoard.winConditions)
})

const gameBoard = {
    winConditions: [[a, b, c], [a, d, g], [a, e, i], [b ,e, h], [c, e, g], 
                   [c, f, i], [d, e, f], [g, h, i]]
}
```

Comment: The value of gameboard has already be assigned before you change the value

Comment: When you add the variables to the array, it doesn't put pointers to the original variables there, it copies their values to the array. That's how Javascript works.

Answer (score 0):

`gameBoard.winConditions;` this line does nothing. When updating the a,b,c... variables, the `winConditions` stay the same. I would recommend to write a function to re-evaluate the value of `winConditions`:

```
let a = 0,
    b = 0,
    c = 0,
    d = 0,
    e = 0
    f = 0,
    g = 0,
    h = 0,
    i = 0;

const test = document.querySelector(".test");
test.addEventListener("click", () => {
    a = 1;
    b = 1;
    c = 1;
    applyWinConditions();
    console.log(gameBoard.winConditions)
})

const gameBoard = {};

applyWinConditions(); // set the win conditions initially

function applyWinConditions() {
  gameBoard.winConditions = [[a, b, c], [a, d, g], [a, e, i], [b ,e, h], [c, e, g], [c, f, i], [d, e, f], [g, h, i]];
}
```